EmailJS. Can not send message. SOLVED
When i am trying to send a message using React with above code:
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser'
const sendEmail = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        emailjs.sendForm('gmail', 'service_*', form.current, 'template_*','public key', )
        .then(
            () => {
            alert('Message successfully sent!');
            window.location.reload(false)
        }, (error) => {
            console.error('Failed to send the message:', error);
            alert(`Failed to send the message: ${error.text}`);
        });
    };


I got the message "Failed to send the message: The Public Key is invalid.

Tying to refresh the Public key and edit the code just like this:
const sendEmail = {
  name: 'James',
  notes: 'Check this out!',
};

emailjs
  .send('SERVICE_ID', 'TEMPLATE_ID', sendEmail, {
    publicKey: 'PUBLIC_KEY',
  })
  .then(
    (response) => {
      console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log('FAILED...', err);
    },
  );


Looking at the docs of that provider, you have to call emailjs.init({publicKey: "..."}) with your public key prior to be able to send emails. Have you done this? Alternatively, you can pass an options object like {publicKey: "..."} to emailjs.sendForm(...) You seem to try passing a string instead of an object ...

@derpirscher Yes, I have tried also to call emailjs.init public key prior but still the same.

Well, then either your key is indeed invalid (something only the provider can clarify) or you have done it wrong (ie you don't show you you are using init) But in principle your second example should work, if we assume your pubic key is valid.

The method can receive up to 4 arguments, and you have 5.

Solved!
Attached the sendEmail function to an event and used e.preventDefault() to prevent the default form submission behavior:
emailjs.init({ publicKey: '*' }); 

const sendEmail = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
var emailData = {
    name: 'Konstantinos Iakovou | Web developer',
    notes: 'Check this out!',
};

emailjs.send('service_*', 'template_*', emailData).then(
    (response) => {
        alert('Message successfully sent!');
    },
    (error) => {
        console.error('Failed to send the message:', error);
        alert(`Failed to send the message: ${error.text}`);
    },
);

};
